# Unhandled exception at 0x00E22277 in Exercise 2.16 - Train Re-arrangement.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000000, 0x002A2000)

Tags: c, exception, stack-overflow

What does this error mean?

> Unhandled exception at 0x00E22277 in Exercise 2.16 - Train
>   Re-arrangement.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters:
>   0x00000000, 0x002A2000).

This stops me from running my program...
I don't get what "Stack Overflow" means and what do I need to do in order to handle this exception?

The whole code is kinda long, so I will summarize it:

it gets user inputs and it goes through a infinite while loop in order to process the input. And by going through if statements and certain cases are satisfied, it breaks and the program terminates + outputting the processed data.

This program runs fine on NetBeans (I have no idea why), but the debugger in Visual Studio says there is an unhandled exception, so it is unable to run....
So, I assume this is easy to fix?

Comment: The most common cause is very deep (or infinite) recursion, though other causes are possible.  Without code, we can't say.

Comment: A stack overflow can happen when you have a method which calls itself, or a method which calls another method which calls the first method. Do you have anything like that?

Comment: If it works in NetBeans then the more typical reason is allocating a very large array as a local variable, a megabyte or more.  Be sure to build the Debug configuration so you'll get an error early before it blows up.  You do have to post code to get an accurate answer.

Comment: @Hans Passant You are right. Because I allocated a large array without using malloc, it was causing problem. Thx!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stack overflows typically occur when you have an infinite recursion, i.e. when a function calls itself (either directly or indirectly) and does not return.  As such each call results in more data on the stack, until there is no more space and the program terminates as you've seen.

Comment: Or when people do silly things like creating VLA's from user input (or, really, using VLA's at all...)

Comment: I didn't use recursion, it was the large array declaration

Comment: Fixed it anyway... Thx for the help guys!